# How to solve "ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql, text

I have been trying on this SQL  work but always giving me errors,I have tried indenting and rewriting my the table but not getting any solution and am new to SQL so is kind of frustrating
this is how it looks like

This is the table;

```
    -> emp_id int,
    -> client_id int,
    -> total_sales int,
    -> primary key(emp_id, client_id),
    -> foreign key(emp_id) references employees(emp_id) on delete cascade, 
    -> foreign key(client_id) references client(client_id) on delete cascade);
```

And always giving me this error;

`ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint`

CAN ANYBODY HELP ME

Comment: Show CREATE TABLE for all 3 tables. FULL code!

Comment: The conditions for successfully creating an FK can be found here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html